# JScript.Net compiler error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, jscript.net

1. I create a .js file containing print("Hello World!");
2. I save it as hello.js
3. I open the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt
4. jsc + Enter
5. jsc \out:hello.exe C:\path\to\my\file.js + Enter

I get an E_ACCESSDENIED error:
what could it be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're running Vista or Windows 2008. The VS2008 command prompt is probably opening in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>`.

Your `/out:hello.exe` switch doesn't specify a path so the compiler is trying to write the compiled exe to the current working folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>` which isn't permitted with out elevated rights (i.e. Run As Administrator).

The solution would be to specify the same path as your source file which is writable:

`jsc /out:C:\path\to\my\hello.exe C:\path\to\my\file.js`

Finally, if you're running 64 bit windows then the working folder path for the command prompt would be: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC`